# combining two dataframe rows of data to the same dataframe row while having the same row size using R

Tags: r

I am relatively new R and I have two dataframes like so:

```
#view(df1) (10x1) dataframe
# A
# NA
# C
# NA
# E
# NA
# G
# NA
# I
# NA
#view(df2) (10x1) dataframe
# B
# NA
# D
# NA
# F
# NA
# H
# NA
# J
# NA
```

I would like my output in R to be as follows

```
#output

#view(df1) (10x1) dataframe

# A
# B
# C
# D
# E
# F
# G
# H
# I
# J
```

I have tried using rbind but it seems to increase the row size, I would like to keep the row size consistent. I have also tried using merge but don't seem to get the right output

dput:

df1:

```
structure(list(A = c("A", NA, "C", NA, "E", NA, "G", NA, "I")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(B = c("B", NA, "D", NA, "F", NA, "H", NA, "J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: How about `df3 = rbind(df1, df2); df3 = df3[!(is.na(df3))]`? Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

This is my non-elegant solution:

Since your rows align and aren't staggered, you need to add some NA rows to your dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)

# Add NA row to the end of df1
df1[nrow(df1)+1,] <- NA

# Add NA row to the beginning of df2
df2 <- rbind(c(NA),df2)

# Merge them with `coalesce`
df3 <- data.frame(coalesce(df1$A,df2$B))
```